# Question for understanding definition of point process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I am trying to understand the definition of point process when reading its [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_process):

> Let $S$ be locally compact second
>   countable Hausdorff space equipped
>   with its Borel σ-algebra $B(S)$. Write
>   $\mathfrak{N}$ for the set of locally
>   finite counting measures on $S$ and
>   $\mathcal{N}$ for the smallest
>   σ-algebra on $\mathfrak{N}$ that
>   renders all the point counts
>
> $$    \Phi_B : \mathfrak{N} \to \mathbb{Z}_{+}, \varrho \mapsto \varrho(B)$$
>
> for relatively compact sets $B$ in
>   $B$-measurable.
>
> A point process on $S$ is a measurable
>   map $ \xi: \Omega \to \mathfrak{N} $ from a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ to the measurable space $(\mathfrak{N},\mathcal{N})$.

My questions are:

1. Is the counting measure the one that
   gives the cardinality of a
   measurable subset, as defined in
   [its Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_measure)? If yes,
   isn't it that there is only one
   counting measure on a measurable
   space, and why in the definition of
   point process, does "write $\mathfrak{N}$
   for the set of locally finite
   counting measures on $S$" imply
   that there are more than one counting
   measures on $S$?
2. > It has been noted[citation needed]
   >   that the term point process is not a
   >   very good one if S is not a subset of
   >   the real line, as it might suggest
   >   that ξ is a stochastic process.

   Is a point process a stochastic
   process?

   If no, when can it be? How are the
   two related?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Every locally finite counting measure on $S$ is of the form $\sum_{x\in \Lambda}\delta_x$ where $\Lambda$ is a locally finite subset of $S$. That is, $\Lambda$ should intersect every compact set only finitely often. Of course, there are infinitely many choices of subset $\Lambda$, and thus plenty of counting measures.

(2) In the case where $S=[0,\infty)$ we can define an integer valued stochastic process by setting $X(t)=\xi[0,t]$. That is, $X(t)$ is the amount of mass that the (random) measure $\xi$ assigns to the set $[0,t]$. For instance, the Poisson process can be expressed in this way. But for a general point process, there may be no notion of a "time parameter" and so it is not thought of as a stochastic process.

Comment: Thanks! I am still wondering about the defintion of "a locally finite subset of S". For better understanding, can "Λ should intersect every compact set only finitely often" be more mathematically rewritten? Must $\Lambda$ be a countable set, so that the sum $\sum_{x\in \Lambda}\delta_x$ can make sense?

Comment: Yes, since $S$ is $\sigma$-compact every locally finite set $\Lambda$ is countable. But not every countable set is locally finite: on the real line compare $\lbrace n: n \geq 1\rbrace$ and $\lbrace 1/n :n \geq 1\rbrace$.

Comment: Thanks! How to understand "Λ should intersect every compact set only finitely often"?

Comment: @Tim I don't know if there is anything better than that sentence. In papers I have seen it expressed as "$|\Lambda\cap K|<\infty$ for every compact set $K$" where $|\ \cdot\ |$ means "cardinality".

Comment: Thanks! (1) Is a point process a stochastic process, if and only if the locally finite counting measure on S all have distribution functions? （2） For a point process $\xi$, is $\xi(A), \forall A \in B(S)$ always a measurable mapping, i.e. random variable? (3) Are there any references regarding my two questions? Thanks!