# Misunderstanding of dirac measure in conjunction with point process

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

While trying to understand random measures and random counting measures, I find myself continually running into a misunderstanding of the dirac function. Although helpful, the answers for [Question for understanding definition of point process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33969/question-for-understanding-definition-of-point-process/33973#33973) lacked some explanation I find I need.

I understand that the dirac measure is defined as

$$\delta_{x}(A) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&1 &&: x\in A\\
&0 &&: x\notin A
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

where $x\in X$, $A\in \Sigma$ and $(X, \Sigma)$ is a measurable space.

From Wikipedia, a *point process* or *random counting measure* is a random measure of the form

$$\mu = \sum_{n=1}^{N}\delta_{X_{n}}$$

where $\delta$ is the Dirac measure and $X_{n}$ are random variables.

My main issue is with $\delta_{X_{n}}$. Since $\mu$ is a measurable function from some probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$ to a set of measures on the borel $\sigma$-algebra of the complete separable metric space $X$, what is the interpretation of $\delta_{X_{n}}(\omega)$ where $\omega\in\Omega$?

Comment: It is $1$ if $\omega=X_n(\omega)$ and zero otherwise.

Comment: So in this case, the probability space would have the underlying set $X$ and underlying sigma algebra $\mathcal{B}(X)$?

Comment: You haven't given enough context for me to be able to tell you what the $\sigma$-algebra is. For all I know $X$ is countable in which case the $\sigma$-algebra is probably just $P(X)$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm interested in the case where $X = \mathbb{R}^{d}$ for some $d\in\mathbb{N}$ with the usual topology. In this case, a random counting measure $\mu$ would be a measurable function from $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ to $(N_{X}, \mathcal{B}(N_{X}))$ where $N_{X}$ is the space of all boundedly finite integer-valued measures on $(X, \mathcal{B}(X))$ and $\mathcal{B}(N_{X})$ some $\sigma$-algebra on $N_{X}$. Is the interpretation of $\delta_{X_{n}}$ here $1$ if $\omega = X_{n}(\omega)$ and $0$ otherwise? If so, does this imply that $\Omega = X = \mathbb{R}^{d}$?

Comment: Your help is very much appreciated by the way and thank you for giving me some of your time!

Comment: Then sure, though there could be any number of sigma-algebras in this context.

Comment: @Ian Your first comment is misleading (and slightly absurd).

Comment: Mm, yeah, though I contest that the situation would be clearer if the domains were specified up front...but yes, I substituted in $\Omega $ in one too many places. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upon further reading and discussion with another user in the comments section, I believe I have come up with a (somewhat) good understanding of the meaning of the dirac measure and the function

$$\mu = \sum^{N}_{n=1}\delta_{X_{n}}$$

The following definition is taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_measure restricted to the case where $X=\mathbb{R}^{d}$, although it can be more general than this.

Given $X = \mathbb{R}^{d}$ for some $d\in \mathbb{N}$, $\mathcal{B}(X)$ the borel $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, and a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$, a *random measure* is a measurable function $\mu: \Omega \rightarrow \mathfrak{N}$ from $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ to the measurable space $(M_{X}, \mathcal{B}(M_{x}))$, where $M_{X}$ is the set of all boundedly finite measures on $\mathcal{B}(X)$.

A *random counting measure* is a random measure $\mu$ of the form

$$\mu = \sum^{N}_{n=1}\delta_{X_{n}}$$

where $N$ is an integer-valued random variable (from $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}))$) and the $X_{n}$ are random variables (from $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$). For any $\omega\in \Omega$, we have

$$\mu(\omega) = \sum^{N(\omega)}_{n=1}\delta_{X_{n}(\omega)}$$

where $N(\omega)\in\mathbb{N}$ and for all $B\in \mathcal{B}(X)$

$$\delta_{X_{n}(\omega)}(B) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&1 &&: X_{n}(\omega)\in B\\
&0 &&: X_{n}(\omega)\notin B
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

Comment: Well done, indeed, $$\mu = \sum^{N}_{n=1}\delta_{X_{n}}$$ means that, for every $\omega$, $\mu(\omega)$ is the measure $$\sum^{N(\omega)}_{n=1}\delta_{X_{n}(\omega)}$$
 and not $$\sum^{N(\omega)}_{n=1}\delta_{X_n}(\omega)$$ One way to remember it is that $\delta_x(\omega)$ is absurd if $\omega$ is in $\Omega$ and $x$ is in the target space of the $X_k$s.